# iPhone Using a Modal View from a TabBar View

Tags: cocoa-touch, uitabbarcontroller, modal-dialog

Using a Modal View from a TabBar View

I always get the following error:
 Error from Debugger: Previous Frame identical to this frame (gdb could not unwind past this frame)

I have an App using a TabBar. From one of the TabViews I need to display
a View modally. I try:

```
if(self.gmailController == nil) {

    self.gmailController =
        [[GMailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"GMailView" bundle:nil];
}

[[self.navigationController] 
        presentModalViewController:gmailController animated:YES];
```

////////

```
And I have tried:

 [self.parentViewController 
        presentModalViewController:gmailController animated:YES];

    and 

 [self.tabBarController presentModalViewController:gmailController animated:YES];

    and 

 [self presentModalViewController:gmailController animated:YES];

 Thanks for reading! Any comments welcome.

 Mark
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check all the connections in your NIB files. I was getting this same error after I changed the name of an IBOutlet variable but forgot to adjust the NIB. This broke the connection between the ViewController and the NIB.

Answer (score 0):

I am sorry. This problem involved my error. I had a problem with the nib file
loading. Once I fixed the NIB, the Modal View loaded with:

[self.tabBarController presentModalViewController:gmailController animated:YES];